# For loop through python dataframe to create multiple dataframes

Tags: python

Python noob here. I have a dataframe with data from multiple years. My goal is to create a for loop to create dataframes for each year in the original df. I need to do this for multiple files hence I want to be able to run a loop through it.

Any help is appreciated!

Here is what I have...

```
years = [2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021,2022,2023]

for x in years:
       [something like this code]
       "y" + str(x) = df[df['Date'].dt.year == x]
       

hardcoded version:
Y2023 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2023]
Y2022 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2022]
Y2021 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2021]
Y2020 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2020]
Y2019 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2019]
Y2018 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2018]
Y2017 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2017]
Y2016 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2016]
Y2015 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2015]
Y2014 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2014]
Y2013 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2013]
Y2012 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2012]
Y2011 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2011]
Y2010 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2010]
Y2009 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2009]
Y2008 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2008]
Y2007 = df[df['Date'].dt.year == 2007]
```

Comment: Use a dict, with the year as key: `y = {x: df[df['Date'].dt.year == x for x in years}`.

Comment: You can also store everything in one dataframe, and use a multi-index with the year as one of the index columns. (I see it's already in one dataframe. I'm not sure if there's a reason to have multiple separate dataframes for each year.)

Answer (score 0):

It is said in the comments, the following code creates a column with the years of the row entries.

```
df[‘year’] = df[‘Date’].dt.year
```

Next you can select the data of one year, e.g. 2022, as follows:

```
df[df[‘year’] == 2022]
```

To create the required data, define the dictionary as follows:

```
y = {x: df[df['year'] == x] for x in years}
```

Note the additional “]”.